# Why doesn't this scipy fourier integration function work?

Tags: python, scipy, numeric

When I try to integrate a periodic array with the scipy function `sp.fftpack.diff(x,order=-1)`, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

For example, when integrating `x=sin(alpha)` to obtain an array of the values of the integral when evaluated from `0` to discrete values up to `2*pi` I get the expected result `-cos(\alphas)`. However, when I use it to calculate the values of the integrals of `x=sin(alpha)+cos(alpha)+1` in the same ranges I do not get the right answer, even when the function is periodic.

I do not understand how this function works. Does someone have an idea?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.diff.html

For example, with this code I obtain the results in the image,I am also comparing the results with the obtained by the trapezoidal rule, which does work when fixing the offset.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJwn3.png)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack as sp
from scipy import integrate as inte
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=150
h=(2*np.pi)/N
x=np.arange(-np.pi,np.pi,h)
y=np.sin(x)+np.cos(x)+1
arrExact=-np.cos(x)+np.sin(x)+x
st=inte.cumtrapz(y,x,initial=0)-2.1
di=sp.diff(y, order=-1)-1
plt.plot(x,di,label='diff')
plt.plot(x,arrExact,label='Exact')
plt.plot(x,st,label='cumpTrapz')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Edit: Well, reading again I realized scipy assumes x[0]=0, however I need to integrate spectrally arrays that do not satisfies this condition, How can I proceed?

Comment: I've tested both of the functions you've mentioned and received really good results. Perhaps it will help if you can post an example of the results you are seeing which are not correct?

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry for the incompleteness, know the results that I have mentioned are there